# OpenJDK login with LDAP

Tags: java, oracle, authentication, ldap, tomcat7

I have a problem with Login with LDAP; I use OpenJDK 11.0.2, tomcat V7 and I use MacOS High Sierra (version 10.13.6)
Following the code:

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

    if(email != null) {
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapUsername);
    }
    if(pwd != null) {
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPassword);
    }
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapServer); 

    log.info("Connecting...");
        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
```

When I get here, I get the following error:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: PROVIDER_URL_ SERVER [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed]
```

If I use Oracle JDK the code works. I changed JAVA_HOME from ORACLE JDK to OpenJDK, do I have to do other operations?

Comment: Hi Valentina. Are you connecting via ldaps or ldap? They use different ports, so you must be sure they're open.

Comment: Btw, also check you have your SSL certificates installed in the OpenJDK version, if you use LDAPS.

Comment: Hi, I am using ldaps with port 636 (with this configuration and Oracle JDK it works fine).
The error is not about to certificate.

Comment: @Valentina are you sure the SSL certificate for LDAPS is installed in the keystore of   OpenJDK? you might have the certificate in the keystore of Oracle JDK but not in the OpenJDK one.

Comment: Did you specify `ldaps:` in the URL?

Comment: @mkhayata The SSL certificate for LDAPS wasn't installed in the OpenJDK keystore 
Solved thanks to everyone!

Comment: @user207421 Yes, I specify ldaps: in the URL. Thanks

Comment: @Valentina I have posted it as an answer it will be good to accept to help anyone else might have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the SSL certificate for LDAPS is installed in the keystore of OpenJDK, you might have the certificate in the keystore of Oracle JDK but not in the OpenJDK one.